# Break loop on null value

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, comparison-operators

I have one source Google Sheet that copies to a number of different Google Sheets for different students. The information copied is for different subjects, each a different sheet on the student's personal Sheets file.

The source sheet is set up to cope with differently sized classes, but my problem is trying to `break` the code when it reaches a section with no information. I don't know why my break statement is not working, since I know that `copysheet` is `null` as it results in an error every time the code runs.

```
function cloneGoogleSheet() {
  //select source sheet
  var sourcesheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('some id');

  var j;
  for (var j = 1; j < 36; j++) {
    //select student sheets to copy to
    var studentid = sourcesheet.getSheetByName("Sheet11")
        .getRange(j, 2).getValue();

    var i;
    for (var i = 1; i < 14; i++) { 
      //select subject name for referencing different sheets
      var subject = sourcesheet.getSheetByName("Sheet6")
          .getRange(i + 1, 7 * j - 5).getValue();

      //find correct subject sheet on student sheet
      var copysheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(studentid).getSheetByName(subject);

      if (copysheet != null) {break;}
      else {
        //copy "importrange" formula from sourcesheet
        var info = sourcesheet.getSheetByName("Sheet6")
            .getRange(i + 1, 7 * j).getValue();

        //copy teacher name from sourcesheet
        var teachername = sourcesheet.getSheetByName("Sheet6")
            .getRange(i + 1, 7 * j - 4).getValue();  

        //copy student name
        var studentname = sourcesheet.getSheetByName("Sheet6")
            .getRange(2, 7 * j - 6).getValue();  

        //paste "importrange" formula into student sheet 
        copysheet.getRange(6, 2).setValue(info);

        //paste teacher name into student sheet
        copysheet.getRange(3, 2).setValue(teachername);

        //paste student name into student sheet
        copysheet.getRange(1, 2).setValue(studentname);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Read about JavaScript comparison operators. Especially `!=` and `==`

Comment: What is the textual error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if (copysheet != null) {break;}
```

to

```
if (copysheet == null) {break;}
```

Comment: Typos are generally advised to resolve via vote to close + comment

Comment: thank you for your help! I found a sample of the code elsewhere and did not know about alternative comparison operators.